# php mongodb sort, query

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to query using the key value I set.

here's what's in the db

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "53166de3456a48980b00001f"
},
"active": 1,
"approved": 1,
"date": "2014-03-04 16:20:51",
"description": "flip blocks to form rows",
"developer": "22",
"iframe": "515",
"image":    "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/f3eNFrgJRwqNprn7VLR0",
 "iosStore": "",
 "key": 1393978851,
 "leader": 0,
  "leaderName": "Default",
  "leaderScore": 0,
  "platform": "html5",
  "plays": 0,
  "playStore": "",
  "pot": 0,
  "rules": "flip blocks to form rows",
  "title": "tet_blocks",
  "type": 1,
   "web": "gamerholic.com/games/tetris/index.html"
 }
```

here's my query:

```
     $key=1393978851
    //tried it both with and without the new mongoID 
    $criteria = array(
    'key'=> new MongoId($key),
     );

    $doc = $collectionBonsai->findOne($criteria);
    $platform = $doc['platform'];
```

platform returns empty, doc returns empty, when the key is clearly in the db and it's the only one in the db with that key. The key is a timestamp. 
Find by the _id also returns empty,
if I do find by user it lists it as one of the documents..

I tried a bunch of other find variations and samething

response is 
        arra(
                )

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to (int)$key and it works now

Comment: That code should actually have thrown an exception for invalid ObjectId

Comment: What driver version is this?